# Member object has no attribute 'author' - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I currently have a ban command, which pretty much calls another function named 'ban_member' - which looks like this:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def ban_member(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    author = ctx.author
    self.staff_log_channel = self.bot.get_channel(designated_channel)

    embed = Embed(description=f'**Moderation Protocol - Ban:**',
                            color = 0x3B0311,
                            timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_author(name=f'{self.bot.user.name}', icon_url = self.bot.user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text= f'Moderator ID: {author.name} │\nMember ID: {member.id}')
    embed.add_field(name=f'You have been banned in {ctx.guild}.', 
    value=f'This decision was articulated by the staff and was decided to be the ' 
    'best action to be taken.', inline=False)

    if reason != None: embed.add_field(
        name=f'**Provided Reason**:', value=f'{reason}', inline=False)

    try: await member.send(embed=embed)
    except: pass

    await self.clearwarn(ctx, member)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.name} has been banned from the server.')
```

Now, the problem is when I call this function using the ban command - I get this error:

`in ban_member -- author = ctx.author -- AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'author'`

I'm trying to have the bot log within the message exactly who banned them using the bot command (aka the person who invoked the command); but it's not letting me.

I've tried multiple things, but none of them worked; as an example of one of them that I could recall off the top of my head:

-I've tried using the audit logs to get the info of the command invoker, but that only displayed the bot as the user who banned the member.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, as I've been going at this for hours to no avail.

Also, please supply some code with any helpful explanations - as I'm relatively new to Python and I'm still learning :)

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here's a snippet of my code which calls this ban function:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['bn'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban_command(self, ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):

#A bunch of embeds and messages to send

await self.ban_member(member, reason=reason)
```

Comment: If the function contained within a class? If it isn't, you need to remove `self` from the parameters

Comment: Why is the command calling another function? The function seems to receive the member as its first parameter instead of a context.

Comment: @Lecdi Yes, the function is contained within a Cog.

Comment: @Ali This function is basically a ban function, which calls the discord.py standard ban feature; I'm doing this because I'm calling this function from multiple commands/events, with one of them being the Ban command that I'll be using; another example would be a spam command which I currently have, which calls the ban function once a member has spammed enough messages.

Comment: How do you call this function? Show a little bit more of you code structure. It looks like the parameters might be mixed up

Comment: @FilipMüller I've edited my original post and added a snippet of my code which calls this function.

Comment: Aren't you missing the `ctx` parameter in that call?

Comment: Yes I am, and my function now works. I'm face-palming like crazy right now . Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

You’ve put `ctx.author` - you need to use `ctx.message.author`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32538303)

Comment: Sorry, I’ve made my answer clearer